# RedBeatScheduler sends new tasks but celery-worker doesn't receive them

Tags: redis, celery, celerybeat

If an celery-worker has about 10-15 tasks, then it stops processing new tasks from RedBeatScheduler which are created dynamically during work. However, if there are less than 10 tasks, then they start working instantly and the worker successfully accepts them.
Restarting processes doesn't help.
But the worker may start receiving this task on its own after a few hours of work randomly.
It only helps to clear all the keys in the Redis and create all the tasks on a new one at startup.

commands:
`celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --queues slow_queue --loglevel=info --concurrency=8 -n cws -E`
`celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --queues celery --loglevel=info`
`celery -A celery_worker beat -S redbeat.RedBeatScheduler --loglevel=debug`

Comment: If the tasks are long-running there is nothing surprising there - with max 8 worker processes it is an expected behaviour, right? Also, I do not recommend running both worker and beat at once. I always run them separately...

Comment: but the tasks that were added earlier are successfully and quickly completed.
the problem is that the worker does not seem to see new tasks, although they are sent. 
increasing the concurrency does not help, tasks just start to run much faster, but new ones still do not start
as if some kind of limit is triggered if there are a lot of tasks

Comment: Is it possible that the beat is sending tasks to the wrong (default) queue? If it is sending to the default queue, it will never be received by the worker you mentioned above.

Comment: No. This sends tasks to the correct queue. The worker just doesn't see them.
If the queue was incorrect, then the tasks would not work at all, and so they stop turning on only when there are a large number of active tasks. I'm afraid I'll have to abandon the Celery because of this and start the processes through the usual endless loop :(